# How to get more logs on ULS

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, uls, log

I have an issue with my BCS Fields.
 When i look in ULS, the logs are very general!! how i can force ULS to get more logs

> 01/11/2019 15:17:05.57    w3wp.exe (0x14B4)                           0x3E74  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://mdosp01.mdo.local:32843/2fed2e93d213448590d44acb02aa93ad/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:c891684d-433c-43ab-bcb8-6575bb4bec4a'  2df7b49e-77cd-20bb-9a5b-5a770dedadb2
>   01/11/2019 15:17:05.57  w3wp.exe (0x14B4)                           0x3E74  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5a    Medium      Calling GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace for Name 'CentralAdministrator' and Namespace 'MDO.BCS.Directory' 2df7b49e-77cd-20bb-9a5b-5a770dedadb2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on the default logging level. You need to enable the verbose logging level to get detailed information.

You can configure it via `central admin > Monitoring > configure diagnostic logging >` over here you have to select the category and from drop-down (**Least Critical event to report to the trace log**) select verbose.

[You can do via powershell and enable more granular level called Verboseex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-sploglevel?view=sharepoint-ps).

```
Set-SpLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx
```

this will set verboseex for all categories....Once you done with torubleshooting please dont forget to reset the logging level.to clear run the below command.

```
Clear-SPLogLevel
```